# Testing condition before inserting records SQL server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that inserts records for actual expenses into a table. When the procedure is invoked the month in question is specified as part of of a variable. For example:

```
exec dbo.upsert_actuals_load_01_load_data 4
```

When the code runs it's supposed to insert the records into the column that corresponds to the month. '1' inserts values into jan_amt, '2' inserts values into feb_amt, etc.

I have written this code:

```
IF @month = 1
   INSERT INTO #actuals_b
           ([forecast_yr_id]
           ,[entry_type]
           ,[unit_cd]
           ,[proj_nbr]
           ,[jan_amt]
           ,[feb_amt]
           ,[mar_amt]
           ...])
     SELECT forecast_yr_id
          , entry_type
          , unit_cd
          , proj_nbr
          , month_amt AS jan_amt
          , 0 AS feb_amt
          , 0 AS mar_amt
          ....
       FROM #actuals;
```

It seems inefficient to have to write the INSERT INTO statement for each IF @month = condition. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The problem seems to be your database design. You shouldn't have a separate column for each month's value (thus 12 columns). You should have 1 column for the month (I assume another for the year), and another for the amount, a total of 2(3). Then you insert a new row for each month.

Comment: except for the table design addressed by @Larnu, you can use 12 `CASE WHEN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Larnu here... but you could build this out dynamically if you use a global temp table in both cases (**or real tables**)... something like:

```
declare @column varchar(64) = 
                            case 
                                when @month = 1 then '[jan_amt]'
                                when @month = 2 then '[feb_amt]'
                                ...
                            end

create table ##actuals_b (...your table definition...)

    declare @sql varchar(max) = '
       INSERT INTO ##actuals_b
               ([forecast_yr_id]
               ,[entry_type]
               ,[unit_cd]
               ,[proj_nbr]
               ,' + @column = ') select * from ##actuals'

print(@sql)
```

This assumes ##actuals only has a single amt column, which seems to be the case based off your static values for the other months.

Comment: You need to encapsulate your `THEN` values in single quotes. Also, I wouldn't recommend global temporary tables. They are an evil entity. :)

Comment: nice catch on the quote... and i personaly never use them, but it is a means to an end in this case if they can't redesign their table. 99% of the time they *claim* they can't so i've given up on showing them how--but your comments are on point +1 from me

Comment: I appreciate the answers and the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, the correct design of your table should be something along the lines of:

```
--All data types are complete guesses
CREATE TABLE actuals_b ([forecast_yr_id] int,
                        [entry_type] varchar(10),
                        [unit_cd] varchar(10),
                        [proj_nbr] int,
                        MonthNum int,
                        Amount decimal(12,2)
                        ...)
```

Then, instead of an `IF...ELSE` or `CASE` expressions, your `INSERT` becomes a much simpler:

```
INSERT INTO actuals_b([forecast_yr_id],[entry_type],[unit_cd],[proj_nbr],MonthNum,Amount,...)
SELECT forecast_yr_id,
       entry_type,
       unit_cd,
       proj_nbr,
       @month,
       month_amt,
       ...
FROM actuals;
```

(Note this is pseudo-SQL in the absence of a full table definition).

Comment: Yes, I can redesign the table. My business users want to see the months presented in columns.

Comment: @Greg then you should be changing the way it is displayed in the presentation layer. The way data is stored, and the way it is presented can, often, be **very** different.

Comment: To make a further example, imagine if you want the total by year. With denormalised data, the query might be: `SELECT [Year], JanAmt + FebAmt + ... + DecAmt AS Total FROM MyTable;`, however, with normalised data it's simply `SELECT [Year], SUM(Amount) AS Total FROM MyTable GROUP BY [Year];`. As you can see above, as well, `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements are far easier as well. Basing the data design on of a user's display preference is rarely a good choice, especially when it's a denormalised format. Have the one/two reports they have with that format; and design your database correctly. :)